# Make a tree from a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, tree

I have a matrix of numbers like this one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nAyC.png)

And I want to create a tree like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16cbm.png)

In the tree, if you do 1+2 (chimp - human) you get the distance in the matrix, which is 3.

My question is: How could I make the tree from the matrix? Which algorithm should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The matrix doesn't contain enough information to reconstruct the tree.

As an example, consider just a matrix containing Human and Chimp. We know he total distance of both branches of the tree needs to be 3, but there's nothing telling us whether it should be 3+0 or 2+1 or 1+2 or 0+3.